Find all values of $a\in\mathbb{C}$ for which the equation $x^4 +ax^2 +a^2x -1=0$ has all roots of the same absolute value

Find all values of $a\in\mathbb{C}$ for which the equation $$x^4 +ax^2 +a^2x -1=0$$ has all roots of the same absolute value

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ be the four roots of the equation, then $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=0$ and $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta=-1$. As all the roots have same absolute value, we can get that all the roots have absolute value 1.
I can't figure out how to proceed further.

I don't know if this can help, but you could also translate the condition that the coefficient of $x$ is the square of the coefficient of $x^2$.

Hint: Show that some two of them sum to 0.

Hint Denote $$f(z) := z^4 + a z^2 + a^2 z - 1 .$$
Each root $r_i$ of the $f$ has modulus $1$ and so $r_i = \frac1{\bar{r}_i}$.

 Thus, $r_i$ is also a root of $$- z^4 \overline{f\left(\frac1{\bar z}\right)} = z^4 - \bar a^2 z^3 - \bar a z^2 - 1.$$ Since these two polynomials are both monic and have the same roots (counting multiplicity), they coincide. Then comparing the coefficients of $z^1$, for example, gives $a = 0$.


Hints towards a solution. If you're stuck with a step, explain what you've tried.
On the complex plane, consider the 4 points $$ A = 0 , B = \alpha , C = \alpha + \beta ,  D = \alpha + \beta + \gamma. $$
(Note that this might not be a proper quadrilateral, as it could be self interesting, have consecutive sides, or not have distinct  vertices.)
Given that all of the side lengths are equal, show that there must be a pair of sides that sum to 0, and so does the other two sides.

 Case 1: If $ A = C$, then $ \alpha + \beta = 0 $.
 Case 2: If $ A \neq C$, construct unit circles at $A, C$ to determine points $B, D$.
 Case 2a: If $B = D$, then $ \beta + \gamma = 0 $.
 Case 2b:  If $B \neq D$, show that $ \alpha + \gamma = 0 $.

Hence, conclude that $ \alpha\beta \gamma + \beta \gamma \delta + \gamma\delta \alpha + \delta \alpha \beta = 0 $.
Hence, $ a = 0 $ is the only possible case.
It remains to verify that this is indeed a solution, which it is.

We can express a monic polynomial in terms of the roots or in terms of the coefficients:
$$(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4) = x^4 + c_3 x^3 + c_2 x^2 + c_1 x + c_0$$
This leads to 4 equations for the polynomial coefficients in terms of the roots
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
0 = c_3 & = - r_1-r_2-r_3-r_4  \tag{1}\\
a = c_1 &= r_1r_2+r_1r_3+r_1r_4 + r_2r_3+r_2r_4 + r_3r_4 \tag{2}\\
a^2 = c_2 &=  -r_1r_2r_3r_4 \left( \frac{1}{r_1}+ \frac{1}{r_2} + \frac{1}{r_3}+ \frac{1}{r_4}  \right)
 \tag{3}\\
-1 = c_0 &= r_1r_2r_3r_4 \tag{4}\\ 
\end{alignat}$$
if the roots $r_i$ are on the unit circle then $1/r_i = r_i^*$ is a reflection of the points along the horizontal axis in the complex plane and we have
$$ \left( \frac{1}{r_1}+ \frac{1}{r_2} + \frac{1}{r_3}+ \frac{1}{r_4}  \right) = (r_1^*+r_2^*+r_3^*+r_4^*) = (r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4)^* = 0$$
Thus in the equation (3) we must have $a^2 =0$
